Coin system in Ursina works on windows, but not on linux
Me and a friend are doing a game on Ursina engine, python. My friend (Which uses windows), says me that the code works perfectly on his machine, meanwhile in my computer, when I run the code, this error comes out:
:linmath(warning): Tried to invert singular LMatrix4.
Assertion failed: !point.is_nan() at line 181 of 
panda/src/collide/collisionEntry.I
Assertion failed: !point.is_nan() at line 181 of 
panda/src/collide/collisionEntry.I
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/javier-illo/.local/lib/python3.12/site- packages/ursina/main.py", line 167, in _update
        __main__.update()
    File "/home/javier-illo/Documentos/programacion/skibidiPomniGame/main.py", line 103, in update
        hit_info = player.intersects()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   

I dont know what's going on in player.intersects(), because it used to work with that line of code, my friend changed a lot of things in the code and stopped working .Here is the code:
from ursina import * from ursina.prefabs.platformer_controller_2d import PlatformerController2d from ursina.prefabs.sky import Sky app = Ursina(fullscreen=True, title="Five Nihts In Anime - Deluxe")

dev=False

#todos los entities aqui porfa (que no sean generados por una clase claro)

sky = Sky() player = PlatformerController2d(y=0, z=.01, scale_z=0, scale_y=2, max_jumps=2, collider="box", gravity=.4, texture="assets/idle.png", color=color.white) ground = Entity(model="cube",z=.01, y=-3, scale_x=30, scale_y=3, collider="box", color = color.green, texture = "grass") world_border = Entity(model="cube",z=.01, x=-6.5, scale_y=10, scale_x=1.5, collider="box", color = color.brown, texture = "brick") pata = Entity(model='cube',z=.01,x=100,y=0, color=color.red, collider = 'box') coin_counter = 0 text_coin = Text('Coins: ' + str(coin_counter), scale=4)

if dev:
    save=open('coordinates.txt','w')
    cur1=Button(model='cube',z=.01,x=0,y=3, color=color.blue,parent=scene, texture="assets/pomni.png")
    cur2=Button(model='cube',z=.01,x=0,y=3, color=color.yellow,parent=scene, texture="assets/pomni.png")
    cur3=Button(model='cube',z=.01,x=0,y=3, color=color.red,parent=scene, texture="assets/pomni.png")
    cur4=Button(model='cube',z=.01,x=0,y=3, color=color.green,parent=scene, texture="assets/pomni.png")
    cur0=Button(model='cube',position=player.position, color=color.black,parent=scene, texture="assets/pomni.png")

#clases

class Coin(Entity):
    def __init__(self, position = (0,0,.01), color=color.yellow,size=(1, 1)):
        super().__init__(
        parent = scene,
        position = position,
        model='cube',
        collider='box',
        origin_y = 0,
        size=(1,1),
        color=color
        )

class Block(Entity):
    def __init__(self, position = (0,0,.01), color=color.brown, texture='brick'):
        super().__init__(
        parent = scene,
        position = position,
        model='cube',
        collider='box',
        origin_y = 0,
        size=(1,1),
        color=color,
        texture=texture
        )

#generacion del nivel

def spawncoin(x,y):
    coin = Coin(position=(x,y,.01))

def spawnblock(x,y):
    block = Block(position=(x,y,.01))

spawncoin(3,3) spawncoin(4,3) for ix in range(8):
    for iy in range(2):
            spawnblock(ix,0-iy)

runCont=0 def run():
    global runCont
    if runCont<0:
        runCont=5
    elif runCont>4:
        player.texture='assets/run1.png'
        runCont -= 0.1
    elif runCont>3 :
        player.texture='assets/run2.png'
        runCont -= 0.1
    elif runCont>2:
        player.texture='assets/run2.png'
        runCont -= 0.1
    elif runCont>1:
        player.texture='assets/run3.png'
        runCont -= 0.1
    else:
        player.texture='assets/run2.png'
        runCont -= 0.1  
#Update

def update():
    if held_keys['a'] or held_keys['d']:
        run()
    else:
        player.texture='assets/idle.png'
    #Capitalism stuff
    global coin
    global coin_counter
    global text_coin
    global hit_info

    destroy(text_coin)
    text_coin = Text('Coins: ' + str(coin_counter), scale=4, origin=(1, -3.5), color=color.yellow, font="assets/comic-sans-ms.ttf")
    hit_info = player.intersects()
    if hit_info.hit and hit_info.entity.__class__ == Coin: 
        coin_counter += 1
        destroy(hit_info.entity)
    if dev:
        cur1.x=cur0.x -1
        cur1.y=cur0.y
        cur2.x=cur0.x
        cur2.y=cur0.y +1
        cur3.x=cur0.x +1
        cur3.y=cur0.y
        cur4.x=cur0.x
        cur4.y=cur0.y -1

        if cur1.hovered:
            cur0.x -= 0.5
        if cur2.hovered:
            cur0.y += 0.5
        if cur3.hovered:
            cur0.x += 0.5
        if cur4.hovered:
            cur0.y -= 0.5

    camera.position = (player.x + 3, 2)
     class Fake(Button):
    def __init__(self, position = (0,0,.01), color=color.white, texture='brick',type=str):
        super().__init__(
        parent = scene,
        position = position,
        model='cube',
        collider='box',
        origin_y = 0,
        size=(1,1),
        color=color,
        texture=texture,
        type=type
        )
        save.write('spawn'+Ftype+'('+str(self.x)+','+str(self.y)+')'+';')

if dev:
    Ftexture=str
    Fcolor=color.yellow
    Ftype='coin'

    def spawnFake(x,y):
        fake = Fake(position=(x,y,.01),texture=Ftexture,color=Fcolor,type=Ftype)

#Controles (excepto los que ya vienen en 'PlatformerController2d') dir = 1 def input(key):
    #patada
    global dir
    if key == 'a':
        dir = 0
    elif key == 'd':
        dir = 1
    if key == 'e':
        if dir == 0:
            pata.x = player.x - 1
        else:
            pata.x = player.x + 1
        pata.y = player.y + 0.5
    else:
        pata.x = 10
        pata.y = 10
    #destructor de realidades (cierra el juego)
    if key == "escape":
        application.quit()
    if dev:
        global Ftype
        global Ftexture
        global Fcolor
        if key=='1':
            Ftype='coin'
            Ftexture='none'
            Fcolor=color.yellow
        if key=='2':
            Ftype='block'
            Ftexture='brick'
            Fcolor=color.brown
        if cur0.hovered:
            if key=='left mouse down':
                spawnFake(cur0.x,cur0.y) app.run()


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Also, extract a [mcve] from your code. Not only for posting here, but also in order to better your understanding of the problem.
